# CSS Media Query Range

Tags: html, css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 275px)
{

    body    
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

I want to make the background color black when it detects 275px - 500px and i want to make the background color blue when it detects 500px - 750px.This is a reference only simply i want to make css codes with different ranges

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a max-width to complete the range:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 275px) and (max-width: 500px)
{

    body    
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 750px)
{

    body    
    {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Also you can write first media query only min width because another media query also set min width.**

```html
@media only screen and (min-width: 275px) {
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 750px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```